# How to use siunitx and tabularx together?

Tags: tables, siunitx, tabularx

I'm using the tabular features of siunitx (for what it is worth: v1.3 since I'm on TexLive 2009) to align numbers in tables, eg.

```
\begin{tabular}{ p{1.5cm} S S S }
bla & 1.23 & 4.5 & 67.89 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

and that works perfectly fine.

Now I would like to have this table span a specific width, or rather to have several tables to have the same width. For this I would normally use tabularx

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{1.5cm} X X X }
bla & 1.23 & 4.5 & 67.89 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
```

Now, is there a way to combine the two? To have the number formatting and alignment features of siunitx inside an automatically resizing table?

Comment: The `X` column in `tabularx` is then converted to `p{<width>}` where *width* is automatically calculated. You can change this by redefining the `\tabularxcolumn` macro like described in the package manual:     `\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{...}`. I'm sure Joseph Wright (author of `siunitx` and moderator here) can tell you what to put for `...`. I'm couldn't find it out for myself yet. (My LaTeX3-fu is still very weak)

Comment: There is a feature request for fixed-width columns for `siunitx`, which I plan to do for version 2.2 (aiming to work on it next month).

Comment: @Joseph: Could you have a look on the solution I came up with now. It seems to work, but I'm not very good in understanding LaTeX3 code.

Comment: @Martin: Usually I'd ask people to 'keep away' from `siunitx` internals - they are not documented and so are liable to arbitrary changes! Your solution is quite nice, with the only thing I'd say being to use `\ExplSyntax(On|Off)` rather than the 'raw' `\catcode` approach you've taken. In `siunitx`, I can't just use a 'p' column as I don't know what options are set when the column is defined - I have to wait until I'm inside the cell!

Comment: @JosephWright In the current manual (2020/02/25), I cannot find any reference to `tabularx`. Because some time has passed since your comment, I want to ask, whether by now there is a built in possibility to use the S cells, but get a similar behaviour as with X cells.

Comment: @Sam There has been fixed-width support for many years, it's just that it's not 'linked' to `tabularx`: look at the `table-column-width` key.

Comment: @JosephWright I already used that key, but I always have to calculate the width. Wouldn't it be cool to have an `X` analog that would automatically span to the entire width available?

Comment: @JosephWright PS: The `table-number-alignment = right` does not work when a fixed width is set. No does `table-text-alignment = right`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `X` column in `tabularx` is then converted to `p{<width>}` where *width* is automatically calculated. You can change this by redefining the `\tabularxcolumn` macro like described in the package manual:

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{<column definition where #1 is the width>}
```

The `S` column uses the `c` column internally. To replace this with `p{<width>}` you have to manually place the internal column definition of `S` into `\tabularxcolumn`. The following code worked in my tests.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begingroup
% Allow `_` and `:` in macro names (LaTeX3 style)
\catcode`\_=11
\catcode`\:=11
% Internal code of `S`
\gdef\tabularxcolumn#1{%
    >{\__siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn S{} }%
    p{#1}%  <- this is different (is `c` in normal `S`)
    <{\__siunitx_table_print:}%
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.5cm} XXX}
     bla & 1.23 & 4.5  & 67.89 \\
     bla & 1.2  & 4.50 &  7.89 \\
     bla &  .2  &  .50 & 67.8 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work. However only with version 2.x of siunitx, not with 1.x due to substantial differences in the syntax.

Comment: @janitor048: Yes, such "patches" are always version dependent. I don't have `siunitx` 1.x right now here, so I can't tell you the right code for it, but the principle should be the same.

Comment: Yeah sure. I mainly wanted to mentioned it for other readers..
I tried to modify your solution for version 1 but the package looks very different from version 2 and I couldn't really find my way through the code. But then, I'm not really familiar with the inner structure of latex packages anyways.

Comment: @janitor048: I've added a v1 answer using the same approach.

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: @Sumit: "doesn't work" doesn't work for me. What is the exact issue? Do you get a compiler error or is the result different of what you expect?

Comment: Does this still work with siunitx v2.6e? I get `! Undefined control sequence. \siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn`

Comment: Does also not work with "siunitx 2015/10/15 v2.6m". Error message `Undefined control sequence. <template> ...box {\TX@col@width }\si@tab@begin@S `

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597660/30810 for an `siunitx` v3 solution.

Comment: Notice that this redefines column type X to be an S column. So all tables in the document with X columns now become siunitx S column with consequences such as text is treated in math mode. Is it possible to instead create a new column type, say, XS instead? Then one could use X when no siunitx is needed and XS when is needed. I guess one needs to use `\newcolumntype` and `\tabularxcolumn` but I can't see how exactly.

Comment: OK, I found it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342564/how-to-make-a-column-specifier-which-combines-x-and-s

Answer (score 8):

Taking Martin's solution and re-coding for version 1 of [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), you'd do something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,tabularx}

\makeatletter
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{%
    >{\si@tab@begin@S[]}%
    p{#1}%  <- this is different (is `c` in normal `S`)
    <{\si@tab@end@S}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.5cm} XXX}
     bla & 1.23 & 4.5  & 67.89 \\
     bla & 1.2  & 4.50 &  7.89 \\
     bla &  .2  &  .50 & 67.8 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you very much!
I'll mark Martin's reply as accepted answer though, because it relates to the more recent version of your package. Hope that's fine with you.

Answer (score 3):

The quite new [tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package seems to be very encouraging. Section 1.5 of its manual introduces explicitly an example for how to embed [siunitx](http://ctan,org/pkg/siunitx)'s »S« columns in »X« columns. Regarding tables this package seems to be an allrounder.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll have a look at it.. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Package is buggy, not compatible with new versions of `array` (on which is based) and not maintained. Its use is not recommended anymore.

Comment: Things change in a decade... It was good while it lasted though

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant of @DavidCarlisle's answer for `siunitx` version 3:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begingroup
% Allow `_` and `:` in macro names (LaTeX3 style)
\catcode`\_=11
\catcode`\:=11
\gdef\tabularxcolumn#1{%
    >{\mode_leave_vertical: \siunitx_cell_begin:w \centering}%
    p{#1}%
    <{\siunitx_cell_end:}%
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.5cm}XXX}
     bla & 1.23 & 4.5  & 67.89 \\
     bla & 1.2  & 4.50 &  7.89 \\
     bla &  .2  &  .50 & 67.8 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Also check https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/423 for improved versions - I removed `\ignorespaces` to make it compile with `\color{red} 4.50`, but alignment of colored cells is still off.

Answer (score 1):

No more need to complex hacking, use `tabularray` package!

With `tabularry` you can have columns that are at the same time `X` type (option `co=<n>`, `n` is the coefficient for the extendable column, usually 1, but you can use 2 to have a column with double width, etc.) and `S` type (option `si=<settings>`).

You don't even have to worry about having non-numeric fields in the `S` columns, using option `guard` where needed.

In the following example, I created a new column type `A` that is both `X` and `S` and has the `table-format` as a parameter. Still, you can also use a `Q` column directly, specifying all the parameters.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-digits=false}
\NewColumnType{A}[1][2.2]{Q[si={table-format=#1},c,co=1]}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
With \texttt{tabularry} you can have columns that are at the same time \texttt{X} type (option \texttt{co=<n>}, where \texttt{n} is the coefficient for the extendable column, usually 1, but you can use 2 to have a column with double width, etc.) and \texttt{S} type (option \texttt{si=<settings>}).

You don't even have to worry about having non-numeric fields in the \texttt{S} columns, using option \texttt{guard} where needed.

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A table with columns that are X and \texttt
{siunitx} at the same time}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[1.5cm]Q[si={table-format=1.2},c,co=1]A[1.1]A},
    row{1}={guard}
    }
    Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3 & Head 4\\
    bla & 1.23 & 4.5 & 67.89\\
    bla & 1.23 & 4.5 & 67.89\\
    bla & 1.23 & 4.5 & 67.89\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A table with vertical lines to show the dimension of the columns}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={Q[1.5cm]*2{A[1.2]}A},
    row{1}={guard},
    vlines
    }
    Head 1 & Head 2 & Head 3 & Head 4\\
    bla & 1.23 & 4.5  & 67.89 \\
    bla & 1.2  & 4.50 &  7.89 \\
    bla &  .2  &  .50 & 67.8 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]