# Conflict between tabu and tabularx, when using siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx, incompatibility, tabularx, tabu

I have many tables set with `{tabularx}` but for some of the it seems easier to use `{tabu}` which works. But if I use both packages and gave the last `X` column in `{longtabu}` an `S` and optional argument it crashes.

So I can “unload” `tabularx` to make it work which is no option or use another tabular preamble but this isn’t so nice …

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu,longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}% comment this out to make it work
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}

\begin{document}
%\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{llX[-0.5,l]{S}X[-0.5,l]{S}X[-0.5,l]{S}}
% works with this preamble even when tabularx is loaded:
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{llX[-0.5,l]{S}X[-0.5,l]{S}X{S}}
    2&  1400&   2,5 &   1,0 &2,3\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

I found [How to use siunitx and tabularx together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12663/4918) but it doesn’t help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`tabularx` is redefining `\arraybackslash` (and it even tells in the docu that this is a hack:

```
\arraybackslash \\ hack.
                 \def\arraybackslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
```

`tabu` doesn't like this definition. It expect `\arraybackslash` to have the meaning from `array.sty`. So now `\\` gives errors. You can give `\arraybackslash` locally the standard definition back:

```
 \begingroup
 \def\arraybackslash{\let\\\tabularnewline}
 \begin{longtabu}
  ....
 \end{longtabu}
 \endgroup
```

Comment: hey that's a revisionist view of history:-) TX defined `\arraybackslash` before there was a `\tabularnewline` so it's not really a re-definition, but yes your solution would work, no need to make it local it would work with TX as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and Ulrike: Thank you both! Works fine now :-)

Comment: @David I didn't wrote anything about the history but described the status of today: tabularx loads array and then overwrites `\arraybackslash`. But I now checked: The changes.txt of latex says that \tabularnewline was introduced 1994 (at your request). Why did tabularx never used it for `\arraybackslash`? And why did array use it when it included `\arraybackslash` in 2003 ("copied from tabularx")?

Comment: "loads array then overwrites". Ah that's a bug I should just lose that line from TX. I think I added the command in all those places, but being consistent with yourself isn't easy, apparently.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hopefully fixed the `\arraybackslash` issue:  http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/latex2e-public/required/tools/tabularx.dtx

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what `tabu` is doing here (I didn't have it installed prior to this) but it looks like something is locally defining `\\` so it no longer ends the table row. using `\tabularnewline` instead seems to make your example work.