# Tabularx can't center some column

Tags: tables, columns, tabularx

I'm trying to create a timetable using tabularx environment, but i can't find a way to center all columns.

Using this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside, landscape]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}\selectfont 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} 

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\tit}[1]{\fontsize{15}{17}\color{darkgray}\usefont{T1}{pplj}{b}{it}\selectfont #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{r >{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X X}
                   & \tit{Lun} &  \tit{Mar} &  \tit{Mer} & \tit{Gio} & \tit{Ven} \\
\toprule
\color{gray}9-11  $||$ &  & Laboratorio III &  &  Metodi mat. per la fisica & Laboratorio III \\ \midrule
\color{gray}11-13  $||$& Meccanica Quantistica & Metodi mat. per la fisica &  & Meccanica Quantistica & Fisica dell'informazione \\ \midrule
\midrule
\color{gray}15-17  $||$ &  & Fisica dell'informazione & Laboratorio III &  & \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

i get this

[image]

where last column is not centered. If i try to change

```
\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{r >{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X X}
```

with

```
\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{r >{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering}X {\centering}X}
```

i get

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\toprule ->\noalign 
                    {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\abovetopsep \global        \@b...
l.39 \end{tabularx}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the package `array`and the the package `tabularx`redefine `\\` in a slightly different way. I refer to [tabularx-can’t-center-some-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43598/conflict-between-tabu-and-tabularx-when-using-siunitx) for a more in depth explanation.

When defining the last column, you have to put in an `\arraybackslash` after the `\centering`-command, *i.e.*:

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
```

Your table preamble will be:

```
\begin{tabularx}{19cm}{r >{\centering}X >{\centering}X%
>{\centering}X >{\centering}X >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

Or you can use [tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu):

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside, landscape]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}\selectfont 
\usepackage{graphicx,tabu}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\tit}[1]{\fontsize{15}{17}\color{darkgray}\usefont{T1}{pplj}{b}{it}\selectfont #1}

\begin{document}
\tabulinesep=4pt

\begin{tabu}to 19cm{r X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]}
\rowfont{\tit} & Lun &  Mar &  Mer & Gio & Ven \strut\\
\toprule
\color{gray}9-11  $||$ &  & Laboratorio III &  &  Metodi mat. per la fisica & Laboratorio III \\ \midrule
\color{gray}11-13  $||$& Meccanica Quantistica & Metodi mat. per la fisica &  & Meccanica Quantistica & Fisica dell'informazione \\\midrule
\midrule
\color{gray}15-17  $||$ &  & Fisica dell'informazione & Laboratorio III &  & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

MWE with `tabu`:

[image]

Comment: An explanation of why `\arraybackslash` is needed would be interesting. The array documentation has `\arraybackslash Restore \\ for use in array and tabular environment (after \raggedright etc.`. Which is less than illuminating. Also, the `\arraybakslash` should be fixed.

Answer (score 6):

in preamble define new column type, for example:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

and then instead >{\centering}X and >{\centering\arraybackslash}X just use for column type C.