# Table not wider than text, same columns' width, decimal alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, scaling

I'd like to

- get the same width of columns labeled 1-10 (all except the first one ~ Name of X)
- be able to adjust the position of "name of Y" (have it centered or on the left. Right now, it's affecting the width of the second column)
- have decimal-aligned numbers
- (decrease table's size by *x* percent? To view its miniature which is set by %?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}   % this package promotes good tabular style
\usepackage{caption}    % for customising caption style
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for decimal alignment

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore.

\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} %length between columns; default = 6
\footnotesize
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = on, justification = centering, labelfont = bf}
        \caption{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
        \begin{tabular}{c*{10}{c}}
            \toprule
            & {Name of Y} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
           {Name of X} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ 
            \midrule
2000    & 123 & 45617 & 1415 & 1111 & 11111 & 55555 & 55555 & 66666 & 777.7 & 88888 \\
2000    & 123 & 45617 & 1415 & 11 & 11111 & 55555 & 55555 & 66666 & 7777.7 & 88888 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}

\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The position of "Name of Y" can be changed using a `\multicolumn`. For the alignment, you can use the `S` column type provided by [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) (the package offers many additional possibilities). To have columns of equal width you could use the `tabularx` package; to make it cooperate with `siunitx`, some additional work is required by adding

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\_=11
\catcode`\:=11
\gdef\tabularxcolumn#1{%
    >{\__siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn S{} }%
    p{#1}
    <{\__siunitx_table_print:}%
}
\endgroup
```

which is nothing more than an update (using the new syntax of siunitx) to **Martin Scharrer**'s answer to [How to use siunitx and tabularx together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12663/3954). In your case, however, the table seems to be really wide, so you could additionally rotate it using `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package (You force the reader to change the reading direction, but the table values are much more clearer).

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % this package promotes good tabular style
\usepackage{caption}    % for customising caption style
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for decimal alignment
\usepackage{tabularx}    % for columns of equal width
\usepackage{rotating}    % for rotating objects

% make tabularx and siunitx cooperate
\begingroup
\catcode`\_=11
\catcode`\:=11
\gdef\tabularxcolumn#1{%
    >{\__siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn S{} }%
    p{#1}
    <{\__siunitx_table_print:}%
}
\endgroup


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore.

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = on, justification = centering, labelfont = bf}
        \caption{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{10}{X}}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Name of Y} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
           {Name of X} & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} & {10} \\ 
            \midrule
2000    & 1.23 & 45.617 & 14.15 & 11.11 & 11.111 & 555.55 & 555.55 & 66.666 & 777.7 & 8888.8 \\
2000    & 12.3 & 456.17 & 1.415 & 11 & 111.11 & 55.555 & 5555.5 & 66.666 & 7777.7 & 888.88 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some other options would be to use `\resizebox` that allows you to scale the table:

```
\resizebox{<width>}{<height>}{<content>}
```

the `!` modifier leaves the natural dimension unaltered. (If the table is too wide, perhaps a portrait display would be better than scaling it):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}   % this package promotes good tabular style
\usepackage{caption}    % for customising caption style
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for decimal alignment

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore.

\begin{table}[!ht]
\footnotesize
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = on, justification = centering, labelfont = bf}
        \caption{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c*{10}{S}}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Name of Y} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
           {Name of X} & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} & {10} \\ 
            \midrule
2000    & 1.23 & 45.617 & 14.15 & 11.11 & 11.111 & 555.55 & 555.55 & 66.666 & 777.7 & 88.888 \\
2000    & 12.3 & 456.17 & 1.415 & 11 & 111.11 & 55.555 & 5555.5 & 66.666 & 7777.7 & 888.88 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}

\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore.

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's also `\scalebox{<x-factor>}[<y-factor>]{contents}`, but using this you need to by trial-error determine the appropriate factor(s).

Another option reducing `\tabcolsep` and still using `\resizebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}   % this package promotes good tabular style
\usepackage{caption}    % for customising caption style
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for decimal alignment

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore.

\begin{table}[!ht]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} %length between columns; default = 6
\footnotesize
\centering
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck = on, justification = centering, labelfont = bf}
        \caption{Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{c*{10}{S}}
            \toprule
            & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Name of Y} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-11}
           {Name of X} & {1} & {2} & {3} & {4} & {5} & {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} & {10} \\ 
            \midrule
2000    & 1.23 & 45.617 & 14.15 & 11.11 & 11.111 & 555.55 & 555.55 & 66.666 & 777.7 & 88.888 \\
2000    & 12.3 & 456.17 & 1.415 & 11 & 111.11 & 55.555 & 5555.5 & 66.666 & 7777.7 & 888.88 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}

\end{table}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
incididunt ut labore.

\end{document}
```

[image]