# How can I define table column by width and align it using siunitx at the same time in a longtable?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand*\fixalign[2][]{\begin{tabular}{@{}S[#1]@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}ccS[table-format=1.1]}
\multirow{2}{4cm}{\strut \Centering Název} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\Centering Premiéra}  &
\multirow{2}{0.8cm}{\Centering Min. doba}  \\
 &\Centering Svět & \Centering ČR &  \\

\Centering Kazatel Kalašnikov &  1.2. & 3.4. & 5.8\\

\Centering Musíme si promluvit o Kevinovi &
\multirow{2}{*}{1.6.} &
\multirow{2}{*}{5.4} &
\multirow{2}{*}{\fixalign[table-format=1.1]{2.8}}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

That compiles into this:

[image]

I would like 5.8 and 2.8 to be aligned. I figure I would need to define colums to have certain width and only then use siunitx, but I am not sure how to do that. (My actual table is much larger and slightly more complicated.)

Comment: I found this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12663/how-to-use-siunitx-and-tabularx-together but I am failing in adapting it to longtable environment.

Comment: I would just leave the `S` columns alone, and add space between columns instead.

Comment: Adding space is not feasible, I am trying to fit as much info on one page (I am actually using `tiny` font size already).

Comment: Then reconsider. Cramming too much information into a small space will not help your readers. S columns are already the narrowest they can be (when configured correctly)

Comment: Well, it is an appendix Iwith raw data that I do not expect anybody to really read, just skim, and I do not want it to run over twenty pages. Even though, on second reading, it might work, but how do I add space between columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, `multirow` is not the answer; I removed the unnecessary packages, add them back if you really need them.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% the following three should be first
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
  >{\Centering}m{4cm}
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.1]
}
Název & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Premiéra}  & {Min.} \\
      & {Svět} & {ČR}                 & {deba} \\

Kazatel Kalašnikov &  1.2 & 3.4 & 5.8\\

Musíme si promluvit o Kevinovi & 1.6 & 5.4 & 2.8 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that seems much simpler, but I would like "název" to be in thmiddle of the first two rows (like in my example), not on the first row. Can that be accomplished?

Comment: Ok, I can put název where I want using multirow. However, if I wanted to have something like 22.8.2012 instead of 1,6 and have it line breaked between 22.8. and 2012, how would I go about it? Right now, I am using parbox with the appropriate width and manual linebreaks (`\\\`), which seems suboptimal.

Comment: Hm, with enough hacks, I am able to print out what I want, so accepting. Even though I am sure you would be appalled if you saw my sourcode. BTW: I use `microtype` everywhere as it is said to improve things in general, `lmodren` as I prefer it (and without it, for some reason lmodern fonts are not used) but `hyphenat` was probably excessive, I am not sure why I still cary it in my standr preamble that I just copy over.

Comment: @sup I'm not saying those packages are not useful: they aren't necessary for the example. If I added them, future readers might think they are.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution without `\newcommand`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}ccS[table-format=1.1]}
\multirow{2}{4cm}{\strut \Centering Název} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\Centering Premiéra}  & \multirow{2}{0.8cm}{\Centering Min. doba}  \\
 &\Centering Svět & \Centering ČR &  \\
\Centering Kazatel Kalašnikov &  1.2 & 3.4 & \multirow{1}{*}{5.8}\\
\Centering Musíme si promluvit o Kevinovi & \multirow{2}{*}{1.6} & \multirow{2}{*}{5.4} & \multirow{2}{*}{2.8}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does not take into account decimal marker (it should be a comma, not a dot, as per sisetup), can that be corrected please?

Comment: Also, no the header (Min. doba) is not aligned with the column (I would like the header to be at the center of the column's content).