# How to use tabularx and siunitx together with siunitx 2.6h / texlive 2015

Tags: tables, siunitx, tabularx

This is a follow up question of this question: [How to use siunitx and tabularx together?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12663/how-to-use-siunitx-and-tabularx-together)

Updating to texlive 2015 (with siunitx 2.6h) seems to have broken the accepted answer. So the question is

How to make siunitx and X column type work together for the very last modification introduced (possibly) in texlive 2015?

Broken MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begingroup
% Allow `_` and `:` in macro names (LaTeX3 style)
\catcode`\_=11
\catcode`\:=11
% Internal code of `S`
\gdef\tabularxcolumn#1{%
    >{\siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn S{} }%
    p{#1}%  <- this is different (is `c` in normal `S`)
    <{\siunitx_table_print:}%
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.5cm} XXX}
     bla & 1.23 & 4.5  & 67.89 \\
     bla & 1.2  & 4.50 &  7.89 \\
     bla &  .2  &  .50 & 67.8 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Output error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<template> ...\TX@col@width }\siunitx_table_collect_begin:Nn 
                                                  S{} \ignorespaces
```

If you consider that this is a duplicate, I will promptly delete this question as soon as someone will add an up-to-date answer to the other question.

Comment: Old answer edited: do you need an explanation of why the change is needed?

Comment: why would you use tabularx for numeric data?

Comment: what should I use?. Please note that the example is a numeric-only data table, while my complete example is a mix of text and numbers.

Comment: Is your question answered by the edit of Joseph? If yes, this post would be a duplicate.