# csvsimple, siunitx and tabularx

Tags: tabularx, siunitx, csvsimple

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\definecolor{ColourTable}{gray}{0.3}
\definecolor{ColourHeader}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{ColourCells}{gray}{0.95}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\DBTable}[2]
{
  \csvloop
  {
    file = #1.csv,
    before reading = 
      \begingroup 
      \ttfamily
      \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.07}
      \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
      \arrayrulecolor{white}
      \sisetup{detect-all=true},
    after head = 
      \begin{tabular}{#2}
      \rowcolor{ColourTable}
      \multicolumn{\csv@columncount}{l}{\color{white}\bfseries #1} \\ \hline
      \rowcolor{ColourHeader} \bfseries 
      \csvlinetotablerow,
    before line = \\ \hline \rowcolor{ColourCells},
    late after last line = \end{tabular},
    after reading = \endgroup,
    command = \csvlinetotablerow 
  }
}

\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{Articles.csv}
ID,Bezeichnung,Price,Stock
A1273,HDMI cable 1.8 m,8.95,45
A1367,VGA cable 3.0 m,4.95,10
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\DBTable{Articles}{l|l|l|l}

% \DBTable{Articles}{l|l|S[table-format=3.2]|S[table-format=2.0]}  

\end{document}
```

which results in the output

[image: Output of the MWE]

I would like to use

1. the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package;
2. the `tabularx` instead of the `tabular` environment.

The first problem is related to the fact that the column headers need to be braced. I do not know, however, how to accomplish this in the `\csvloop` command.

As for the second problem, when I replace `tabular` by `tabularx` adding a certain width and a stretchable column type, I get an error.

**Edit**

My ultimate goal is to generate the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\definecolor{ColourTable}{gray}{0.3}
\definecolor{ColourHeader}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{ColourCells}{gray}{0.95}

\begin{filecontents*}{Articles.csv}
ID,Bezeichnung,Price,Stock
A1273,HDMI cable 1.8 m,8.95,45
A1367,VGA cable 3.0 m,4.95,10
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

% \DBTable{Articles}{10cm}{l|X|S[table-format=3.2]|S[table-format=2.0]}

\begingroup
\ttfamily
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.07}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\sisetup{detect-all=true},
\begin{tabularx}{10cm}{l|X|S[table-format=3.2]|S[table-format=2.0]}
\rowcolor{ColourTable} \multicolumn{4}{l}{\color{white}\bfseries Articles} \\ \hline
\rowcolor{ColourHeader} ID & Bezeichnung & {Price} & {Stock} \\ \hline
\rowcolor{ColourCells} A1273 & HDMI cable 1.8 m & 8.95 & 45 \\
\rowcolor{ColourCells} A1367 & VGA cable 3.0 m & 4.95 & 10
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

automatically from the CSV file using the `\DBTable` command exhibiting paramaters for (1) file name, (2) table width and (3) column specifications.

Is this possible at all based on the `csvsimple` package? Would it be better to parse the CSV file, e.g., using LaTeX3 commands?

Comment: Off-topic: You shouldn't load the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages independently of each other. To maximize mutual compatibility, write `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: Relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12665/134641